# Function with arguements inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Can someone please help why this is not working.

HTML Code:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="adminDBDisplay(ownorg);" >OOrg</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="adminDBDisplay(twoorg);" >Twoorg</a></li>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function adminDBDisplay(db){
        alert("Got into function" +db);
        // Planning to use jQuery Ajax here
    } 
});
```

When I look using Firebug, I get following error:

```
"ReferenceError: adminDBDisplay is not defined"
```

Can someone please help me why this is not working. There something wrong on how I am approaching this. Please let me know if there are better ways. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's because that function is defined within the `ready()` function. The DOM will parse `before` any `.ready()` is called. This means that the name of that function isn't available at the time of the DOM processing. Simply move that function *outside* of the `.ready()` and you'll find it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining a function with `function name() {...}`, if you are already inside a function, then it will only be defined in that function.

Function definitions should not be wrapped in a `.ready()`, since they don't run until they are called. Remove the `.ready()` wrapper and you should be good to go.

Comment: oh I get it. I used it outside the function it was working. What if I have to use Jquery AJAX inside adminDBDisplay(db) function please?

Answer (score 1):

The following notation:

```
$(function() { ... });
```

itself is a function that binds `function() {...}` to `document.ready`. And running function `adminDBDisplay(db){...}` in `document.ready` only defines the function it at runtime, but doesn't actually call it. In order to call it, you would want `adminDBDisplay('parameter');`

To effectively implement it, you'll want to place it within the body of your page as follows:

```
<head>
<script src="yourversionofjquery.js"></script>
<script>
//Defining your function for calling later
function adminDBDisplay(db)
{
    alert("Got into function" +db);
    //Planning to use Jquery Ajax here
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
//Binding an anonymous function to document.ready
$(function () {
        //Do whatever you want after document.ready
    });
</script>
<div> rest of body</div>
</body>
```

Let me know if that makes sense/fixes your errors.

EDIT: also, put 'single quote' around 'ownorg', like "adminDBDisplay('ownorg');" otherwise it's looking for a variable called ownorg.